# Book that is more accessible than Shoenfield

Tags: reference-request, logic, self-learning

My logic course is based on my Computer Science education and on some random Internet pages (mostly Wiki). I want to make my knowledge of logic more coherent and fill in missing gaps. Thus I started reading  Shoenfield's "Mathematical Logic" but I don't like this book. I found it to terse (almost no examples) and quite vague. I would like to read something more accessible yet rigorous enough about first order logic and something really brief and basics about model theory. I study by myself so I need some exercises, best with answers (no need for full solution) so I can be reassured that I understand topic well.

Comment: I think Enderton is much more accessible. There is also this wonderful little book called _Metalogic_ by Hunter, but it doesn't look so good, typographically speaking. [Peter Smith](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/35151/peter-smith) has written a wonderful guide that might be helpful here, check [it](http://www.logicmatters.net/students/tyl/) out (Appendix 6 talks about Enderton).

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with the suggestion of Enderton's book. But I would avoid Hunter's book. My memory from when I looked at it last is that the exposition is poor in several ways, and the terminology is not standard,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it is "wonderful" as Hunan Rostomyan very kindly says, but for what it is worth here's [a link to] an extensive Guide to the textbooks out there:

> http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl

And yes, Shoenfield's *Mathematical Logic* is almost certainly not the place to start (it is indeed "terse", though "vague" is the wrong word -- "tough" would be better!). So certainly, don't be put off learning more logic by the fact that you found that particular book hard going. If you have a bit of maths/compsci background, you could find the widely available book by Enderton works well -- but there are other suggestions in the Guide. Just browse through a few options till you find one at the level that suits you best.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I used your guide and now I really understand the point of this endeavor and I think I own you a big hug. I picked Chiswell and Hodges and I am currently giving it a try. For 10 pages I have already read it really looks like lucid book. I will try to write few more words on this book for future generations when I read more. The problem with Shoenfield's book was that I could easily recognize and understand concepts I already knew but I was almost unable to understand new concepts so I didn't see any point in reading it other than recalling my old knowledge.

Comment: So I have started reading second chapter and I can definitely say that Chiswell and Hodges is very accessible book with a lot of exercises.

Comment: Link obsolete. New link: http://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/

Comment: Thanks @HansLundmark: I've substituted the more stable url

Comment: @Peter Smith: I am impressed with the TYL guide. One book I would recommend you to review is Monk's book on logic. Although the typography and notation make it hard to use for a first book, the content is exceptional. For example, there are full chapters on decidable and undecidable theories which I turn to first whenever I need a reference on the subject.

Comment: Thanks @CarlMummert -- Yes, Monk's text is on my list of shortly-to-be-reviewed Big Books. (So many logic books, so little time ....!)

Answer (score 1):

When I teach a course on this at the undergrad level, I use Enderton's book *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*. It is very well written, and it conveys the right viewpoint, in a certain sense.

An online resource is a set of lecture notes by Stephen Simpson, which you can find [on his webpage](http://www.personal.psu.edu/t20/notes/). The "Mathematical logic" and "Foundations of Mathematics" notes cover about two semesters of introductory logic.

For model theory, a reasonable and modern book, which is not too advanced at the beginning chapters, is Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*.

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend Elliot Mendelson's 'Mathematical logic', CRC Press?  Earlier editions were not nicely printed but later ones are ok.  One problem with later editions is that they have been padded with material not really at the heart of the subject - but you can skip them!  Solutions to many (but not all) of the exercises are included.  The rudiments of model theory are included.

Comment: You dug up really old topic. I gave a try to Chiswell book and I was more then pleased. Maybe when I am in mood for logic again I will give a try to this book.